# Facebook Graph API: Can only display 100 posts

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have just began to start dabbling in JSON and Facebook's Graph API. With the following I've been able to pull posts from my Facebook page:

```
$page_id = '???';
$access_token = '???';

$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?access_token=' . $access_token . '&limit=100');
$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($fbdata->data as $post ) {
    $posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->story . '</a></p>';
    $posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->message . '</a></p>';
    $posts .= '<p>' . $post->description . '</p>';
    $posts .= '<br />';
}

echo $posts;
```

However Facebook doesn't allow any more than 100 posts in one JSON request. Is there a way around this by making multiple requests or should I be going about this in a different way entirely?

Does anybody know how I could display all existing posts from my Facebook page?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Without that we can't help.

Comment: @BRO_THOM Sorry, I should have explained more clearly. As far as I'm aware Facebook only allows you to pull out 100 posts in one JSON request. I need to find a way to either make multiple requests until all the posts are shown or I need to go about this in a different way completely.

Comment: I see your problem then. You should trigger a ajax or pjax call at the moment the end of the 100 posts is reached, to get another 100 posts. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more info.

Comment: @BRO_THOM Thanks for the suggestion! I understand the basics of Ajax, however I'm unsure on how I'd request posts from further down the feed.

Comment: Normally you would use a method called pagination together with ajax to determine on which "page" or "index" the user currently is. Unfortunately it's pretty difficult to build such a system from scratch. I would advise investing into getting to know frameworks and MVC structured since these simplify usage that sort of code a lot. Edit: https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/pagination/ seems to have all the plugins you need for pagination.

Comment: @BRO_THOM I've had to make custom pagination many times before, I'm just unsure on how to physically request posts that are further down in a timeline from Facebook, I don't know whether the Graph API has this functionality or not.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you there. Maybe you should consult the Facebook API documentation as to find out if it's allowed to make ajax calls and if there's even support from their end.

Comment: @BRO_THOM I'll have a look and see what I can find. Thanks for all your help! :]

Comment: No problem dude! Let me know how it works out, for the sake of historical value as well.

Comment: @BRO_THOM Sure,I'll make sure to post any findings as an answer to the question.

Comment: Hm.. what happens if you remove the limit parameter? Will you still just get 100 posts from that request?

Comment: @BRO_THOM Check out what I've got so far, posted it as an answer. Managed to paginate everything quite simply with PHP, just have one little issue.

Comment: Good job! Maybe for the 'next' issue you can simply get the last number of posts and if this is 0 or null, simply set the 'GET' to a null.

Comment: @BRO_THOM Why thank you! The pagination works by offsetting the posts, this is a feature of the Graph API. I could always check if there is a number of posts less than the limit per page, although this wouldn't work if the number of posts on the last page were equal to the offset.

Comment: Doesn't $fbdata->data become null when there are no results?  Or at least sizeof($fbdata->data)? If so you can use that to indicate the end.

Comment: @BRO_THOM Thanks again for all your help! I've got it working perfectly nowl

Comment: No problem dude! It might also be a good idea to actually save/send the offset as a variable so you can reuse the code and maybe even make it suitable for 'show 5','show 10' etc via a select element.

Answer (score 1):

An infinite amount of posts can be displayed by paginating them like so:

```
//Set page variable/page number

if($_GET['page'] == 0) {
    $page = 1;
}
else {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

//Page increments/decrements
$next_page = intval($page + 1);
$prev_page = intval($page - 1);

//Set offset if it isn't the first page
if ($page > 1) {
    $offset = $page * 5 - 5;
} 

//Facebook Dev details
$page_id = '???';
$access_token = '???';

//Get JSON for specified page
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?access_token=' . $access_token . '&limit=5' . '&offset=' . $offset);

//Interpret the data
$fb_data = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($fb_data->data as $post ) {
    $posts .= '<p><a href="http://facebook.com/' . $post->id . '">' . $post->story . '</a></p>';
    $posts .= '<p><a href="http://facebook.com/' . $post->id . '">' . $post->message . '</a></p>';
    $posts .= '<p>' . $post->description . '</p>';
    $posts .= '<br />';
}

//Display posts
echo $posts;

//If page isn't the first page add previous button
if ($page > 1) {
    echo '<a href="?page=' . $prev_page . '">' . 'Previous' . '</a>';
} 

//Total offset of posts on next page
$next_page_offset = $offset + 5;

//Make next page object
$json_next_page_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?access_token=' . $access_token . '&limit=5' . '&offset=' . $next_page_offset);

//Get JSON for next page
$fb_next_data = json_decode($json_next_page_object);

//Echo next button if size of next data is greater than one
if( sizeof( $fb_next_data->data) > 0 ) {
    echo '<a href="?page=' . $next_page . '">' . 'Next' . '</a>';
}
```

Probably needs some improvement, but it works as desired so far.

I hope what I've got so far can help others in making a basic and easy to manage Facebook feed :]